# mount 2 different directory to the same local directory

Tags: linux, mount

What will happen if two different directories will be mounted on the same local directory? i would like to know if its possible, and if so, why?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can but only last mount is active (so you don"t see or access files from the previous one)...

but It will always be a bad idea .... source of error, confusion & so on....

Comment: I don't think this is true. Both mounts will be active, and open files from the previous mount will still be accessible.

Comment: no try it you won't see files from first mount so you cannot access them (file not found)  :)  but of course if they are opened first, they are still opened after second mount ... :)